# Reading from EEPROM, and knowing that its not written at the start up

Tags: c, embedded

I write a structure into EEPRM as follows

```
typedef struct
{
   fract32 AmpF; // amplitude fundamental
   fract32 AmpH; // amplitude harmonic 
   UINT32 b;
   UINT16 d;
   UINT16 crc;

}CoilBoardAmp_T;

// mechanic angles and salt water angles of coil stored in coil-eeprom
typedef struct
{
    ChannelData_T     channel[NUM_CHANNELS];
    CoilBoard_T       coilboard;
    CoilBoardAmp_T    coil_h;
    CoilBoardAmp_T    coil_d;
//  UINT32    gCoilSerialNumber;
//  UINT32    gInversSerialNumber;
} Coil_Eeprom_Data_T;
```

I set that data by a software, which writes to that structure.

The problem is when reading that structure at the first time without writing to it, I read false data.

I need to detect that point. How would I know If the data that is read is false, or how would I know that I read the data without the software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) or [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) at the end of your structure, which is calculated on all the structure's members.

When you write the data to the EEPROM you calculate the value of the checksum and write it. When you read the data from the EEPROM, you calculate the checksum of this data and compare it with the checksum of the data you've just read, and if it does match it means (with a high probability) that your data is correct.

Basically if we represent your structure in memory :

```
byte |0 1 2 3|4 5 6 7|8 9 10 11|12 13|14 15|
       AmpF    AmpH      b        d    CRC
```

Then the 2-bytes CRC could be calculated like this :

```
CRC = (AmpF<<2) + (AmpF & 0x00FF) 
    + (AmpH<<2) + (AmpH & 0x00FF) 
    + (h<<2)    + (h & 0x00FF) 
    + d;
```

Which could obviously be optimized with a `for` loop. I'm quite sure there are examples on the 'Net but an idea would be to go from the address of your structure to this address + sizeof(struct) - sizeof(CRC) by steps of 2 bytes.

Internet is full of implementations for checksums and CRCs that go from extremely simple to very complicated, depending on what you want to achieve and your system capabilities, but basically a simple checksum is just the addition of all the bytes in your data structure.

A simple checksum like the one I gave as an example only detects wrong bits in your data, you wouldn't detect if two values are swapped, e.g. AmpF and AmpH.

Note that though checksums and CRCs are a different thing, both terms are often used to designate the other.

Comment: what If the checksum is error, that means the user should write the structure by the software ?

Comment: If the checksum you compute does not match the checksum you read it means you can't consider the data you read as valid. It might be because you haven't written it before, or because it was corrupted. It's up to you to deal with it in your error management. But be aware of the limitations of a checksum, if you have the capabilities of doing a CRC it's probably worth doing it !

Comment: I never heared a checksum being called CRC.

Comment: @Olaf I wish I could say the same but I face it almost everyday. Maybe it's regional, or just my company, who knows.

Comment: @TimF: Oh, the other way 'round is pretty common. But CRC for checksum is not a good reference for whoever it uses.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to have an additional byte `check_eeprom` in EEPROM. This is read before reading the structure. At the first time, you can write 0x55 into this byte. If you read this byte as 0x55, then EEPROM is set with valid values, else you need to initialise it. This check can be done in the init routine

```
// read check_eeprom from eeprom
if (check_eeprom == 0x55)
{
   // Normal operation
}
else
{
   // First time. Write default values

   // write 0x55 into check_eeprom location
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach shall be setting a FLAG at the time of first read to help in determining whether it is first read or not.

While performing the read operation, check whether the FLAG is set. If the FLAG is set, then perform usual reading and processing. If the FLAG is not set, then it means that it is the first read and so fill the structure with default values. Ensure that the FLAG is set at the end of first read operation.